# Copy files (and existing folder structures) to new location using dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df):

```
df =  structure(list(site = c(989L, 989L, 990L, 990L), filename = structure(1:4, .Label = c("989_1.csv", "989_5.csv", "990_2.csv", "990_9.csv"), class = "factor"), sourceA = structure(1:4, .Label = c("FolderA/989/989_1.csv", "FolderA/989/989_5.csv", "FolderA/990/990_2.csv", "FolderA/990/990_9.csv" ), class = "factor"), destination = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L ), .Label = c("FolderB/989/989_5.csv", "FolderB/990/990_9.csv", "FolderC/989/989_1.csv", "FolderD/990/990_2.csv"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("site", 
"filename", "sourceA", "destination"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

'FolderA' has a series of subfolders containing a number of files. I wish to copy subsets of these files to other folders (shown here as 'destination'). Note: 1) the destination varies from file to file, and 2) the primary folders (FolderB,FolderC,and FolderD) exist, but the subfolders do not (e.g., FolderC/989/).

I believe my solution may involve the file.copy() function, but I am having no success.

```
file.copy(df$sourceA, df$destination)
```

results in

```
Error in file.exists(from) : invalid 'file' argument
```

Ideas?

Edit: using column name 'source' was causing problems - changed to 'sourceA'.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the class of `df$sourceA` is `'factor'` and `copy.file` wants a `'character'`.